# how to add a number to a summed number

Tags: javascript, sum

I would like to add the products and total them. 99.99 should be added to the total amount.

what options are there?

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2qDq.jpg).]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn-add').click(function() {
    $('#select-from option:selected').each(function() {
      $('#select-to').append("<option value='" + $(this).val() + "'>" + $(this).text() + "</option>");
      $("input[name='class']").val((parseFloat($(this).val()) + parseFloat($("input[name='class']").val())).toFixed(2));
    });
  });
  $('#btn-remove').click(function() {
    $('#select-to option:selected').each(function() {
      $('#select-from').append("<option value='" + $(this).val() + "'>" + $(this).text() + "</option>");
      $(this).remove();
      $("input[name='class']").val(parseFloat($("input[name='class']").val() - parseFloat($(this).val())).toFixed(2));
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="selectfrom" id="select-from" multiple="" size="5">
  <option value="0.00">--</option>
  <option value="22.99">Product S</option>
  <option value="27.99">Product S Boost</option>
  <option value="32.99">Product S Boost</option>
  <option value="37.99">Product M</option>
  <option value="42.99">Product M Boost</option>
  <option value="47.99">Product L</option>
  <option value="62.99">Product XL</option>
</select>

<a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="btn-add">Add »</a>
<a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="btn-remove">« Remove</a>

<select name="selectto" id="select-to" multiple="" size="5"></select> 
<input type="text" name="class" value="0">
<div type="text" id="classx">Here the total number including €99.99 should be calculated</div>
```

Comment: Could you clarify when you want to add to where? I could not fully understand the question

Comment: Each time a product is added, the total is calculated. I would like to add 99.99 to this total.

Comment: SO if the current total of 2 items is 50.98 you would like to display the 149.98? And where would you like to display it? In the most right input ?

Comment: the output should appear here :<div type="text" id="classx">Here the total number including €99.99 should be calculated</div>div>

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood what you're asking, you want to add `99` to the summed value. As such, you could simply perform this mathematical operation on the sum before you update the `input`.

However, there's a few things you can do to make the code more succinct and take advantage of jQuery.

Firstly, you don't need to add the `option` elements back in to `select-from` when removing items. This duplicates them.

Secondly, you can just `clone()` elements instead of hacking together HTML strings and appending that content. This avoids the need for the explicit `each()` loop.

Lastly, you can use `reduce()` to sum the selected options and update the `input` once, outside of the loop.

Here's a working example with the above changes, and DRY'd up slightly:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  const $totalField = $('#total');
  const calcTotal = () => {
    let total = [...document.querySelectorAll('#select-to option')].reduce((s, el) => s + parseFloat(el.value), 0);
    return total > 0 ? total + 99 : total;
  }

  $('#btn-add').click(e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#select-from option:selected').clone().appendTo('#select-to');
    $totalField.val(calcTotal().toFixed(2));
  });

  $('#btn-remove').click(e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#select-to option:selected').remove();
    $totalField.val(calcTotal().toFixed(2));
  });
});
```

```css
select {
  min-width: 150px;
  min-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="selectfrom" id="select-from" multiple="" size="5">
  <option value="22.99">Product S</option>
  <option value="27.99">Product S Boost</option>
  <option value="32.99">Product S Boost</option>
  <option value="37.99">Product M</option>
  <option value="42.99">Product M Boost</option>
  <option value="47.99">Product L</option>
  <option value="62.99">Product XL</option>
</select>

<a href="#" id="btn-add">Add »</a>
<a href="#" id="btn-remove">« Remove</a>

<select name="selectto" id="select-to" multiple="" size="5"></select>

<input type="text" name="class" value="0" id="total" value="0.00" />
```

Also, as an aside, note that you're using a *very* old version of jQuery. The latest version at the time of this question is v3.7.1. I would strongly suggest you update.

Comment: that looks great. can the 99.99 be removed from the input once I have emptied the select list.

Comment: Sure, updated with an example.

Comment: thank you, that worked great. I answered above and posted a code, which unfortunately doesn't work. Can you please check the code to see where the error is.

Comment: That's not how this site works. That space is for others to answer your question. If you need additional help, please open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

DRYed up further

```js
$(() => {
  const $totalField = $('#total');
  const calcTotal = () => {
    let total = $('#select-to option')
      .map((i, el) => +el.value)
      .get()
      .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
    return total > 0 ? total + 99 : total;
  };
  $('.btn').on('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const tgt = e.target.closest('.btn');
    if (!tgt) return; // not a button
    if (tgt.matches('.add'))
      $('#select-from option:selected').clone().appendTo('#select-to');
    else $('#select-to option:selected').remove();
    $totalField.val(calcTotal().toFixed(2));
  });
});
```

```css
select {
  min-width: 150px;
  min-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="selectfrom" id="select-from" multiple="" size="5">
  <option value="22.99">Product S</option>
  <option value="27.99">Product S Boost</option>
  <option value="32.99">Product S Boost</option>
  <option value="37.99">Product M</option>
  <option value="42.99">Product M Boost</option>
  <option value="47.99">Product L</option>
  <option value="62.99">Product XL</option>
</select>

<a href="#" class="btn add">Add »</a>
<a href="#" class="btn remove">« Remove</a>

<select name="selectto" id="select-to" multiple="" size="5"></select>

<input type="text" name="class" value="0" id="total" value="0.00" />
```